# Irreducible but not geometrically irreducible component of Hilbert scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes

If $K$ is a field, is there an irreducible component of the Hilbert scheme ${\rm Hilb}_{\mathbb{P}^r_{K}}$ that is not geometrically irreducible?

Comment: Such examples should arise from Vakil's work on "Murphy's Law" for Hilbert schemes.